# Rsync through bastion host using different port on destination server

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to run an rsync through a bastion host onto an SSH server that listens on a non-standard port, like this:

Source Host -> Bastion Host -> Destination Host (sshd on non-standard port)

I can get onto the destination host via the Bastion box using this:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p admin@bastion-host" user@destination-host`

But this gets me onto the "default" SSH server, running on port 22, and not the one I want to get to, which, for sake of argument, is running on port 12345.

If I want to rsync using the non-standard port, the examples I can find, like this for example:

https://www.tecmint.com/sync-files-using-rsync-with-non-standard-ssh-port/

Indicate I should use -p, but that wouldn't work since I need port 22 all the way through the tunnel until the end.

How can I rsync to/from this destination server on port 12345, via a tunnel through the bastion server on the standard port 22?

Source Host (22) -> Bastion Host (22) -> Destination Host (12345)

Comment: `-p 12345` should apply only to the final destination as long as it's outside the quoted `ProxyCommand` parameter. If it's put inside that quoted parameter, it should apply only to the connection to the bastion host.

Comment: That didn't seem to work because when I tried `ssh -p 12345 -v -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p admin@bastion-host" user@destination-host`, I could see it trying to connect to my bastion host on port 12345

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. My destination server was only allowing port 22 from the bastion host, and not the non-standard port.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I figured it out. My destination server was only allowing port 22 from the bastion host, and not the non-standard port.